# Discord bot: attaching a random image from list (Python)

Tags: python, file-upload, discord, discord.py

I am making a discord bot for my friends discord server that simply chooses a random image from a list of images.

here is some code

```
my_files = [
    discord.File(r'C:\Users\TT1-2-181130-01\Desktop\Python\Faces\Face_1.jpg'),
    discord.File(r'C:\Users\TT1-2-181130-01\Desktop\Python\Faces\Face_2.jpg'),
    discord.File(r'C:\Users\TT1-2-181130-01\Desktop\Python\Faces\Face_3.jpeg'),
    discord.File(r'C:\Users\TT1-2-181130-01\Desktop\Python\Faces\Face_4.jpg'),
    discord.File(r'C:\Users\TT1-2-181130-01\Desktop\Python\Faces\Face_5.jpg'),
    discord.File(r'C:\Users\TT1-2-181130-01\Desktop\Python\Faces\Face_6.jpg'),
    discord.File(r'C:\Users\TT1-2-181130-01\Desktop\Python\Faces\Face_7.jpg'),
    discord.File(r'C:\Users\TT1-2-181130-01\Desktop\Python\Faces\Face_8.jpg'),
    discord.File(r'C:\Users\TT1-2-181130-01\Desktop\Python\Faces\Face_9.jpg'),
    discord.File(r'C:\Users\TT1-2-181130-01\Desktop\Python\Faces\Face_10.jpg'),
    discord.File(r'C:\Users\TT1-2-181130-01\Desktop\Python\Faces\Face_11.jpg'),
    discord.File(r'C:\Users\TT1-2-181130-01\Desktop\Python\Faces\Face_12.gif'),
    discord.File(r'C:\Users\TT1-2-181130-01\Desktop\Python\Faces\Face_13.jpg'),
    discord.File(r'C:\Users\TT1-2-181130-01\Desktop\Python\Faces\Face_14.jpg'),
    discord.File(r'C:\Users\TT1-2-181130-01\Desktop\Python\Faces\Face_15.jpg'),
    discord.File(r'C:\Users\TT1-2-181130-01\Desktop\Python\Faces\Face_16.jpg'),
    discord.File(r'C:\Users\TT1-2-181130-01\Desktop\Python\Faces\Face_17.jpg'),
    discord.File(r'C:\Users\TT1-2-181130-01\Desktop\Python\Faces\Face_18.jpg'),
    discord.File(r'C:\Users\TT1-2-181130-01\Desktop\Python\Faces\Face_19.jpg'),
]

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready")

@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send(choice(my_files))
```

but when I run the code and type `!test`, it just shows something like:

```
<discord.file.File object at 0x04BF8E60>
```

in the discord server, instead of the actual image. does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Files are sent as the `file` keyword argument](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.send)

```
await ctx.send(file=choice(my_files))
```